# React styled-components - How to render styles based on prop condition or pseudo class?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I am trying to conditionally render a hover state / view within styled-components, leveraging the props coming in from react...

Currently, my code looks something like this:

```
${isHovered}, &:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

Unfortunately, this does no work to be able to have a true/false as I am missing something I presume to be able to do the either / or pseudo..

**I want to be able to explicitly show the hover state while retaining the default pseudo hover. How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Not elegant but should work `background: ${props => props.isHovered ? 'red': 'inherit'}; &:hover { background: red}`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko ah, this does work, but, causes A LOT of duplication of code.. would be nice to have it just something as simple as `variable, &:hover` in order to cover both instances :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have your selectors right now is invalid:

#### Problem

```css
${isHovered}, &:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

As of now, this will always translate to:

```js
undefined, &:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

For simplicity, in order to interpolate properly, it must be a function accepting `props` that returns a `string`:

```css
color: ${props => props.isHovered && "pink" };
```

On a related note, even if you wrapped your styled component in a higher order component where `isHovered` is defined as an argument, it unfortunately still won't work in production for styled-components v5 -- this worked in v4, but v5.x doesn't handle [css interpolations](https://github.com/dminkovsky/next-styled-broken-prod/blob/master/pages/index.js#L18-L41) properly within a styled component when compiled for production (see issue tracker [here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3026)).

#### Solutions

A better and recommended approach would be to interpolate within a CSS property:

```js
  background: ${({ isHovered }) => isHovered && "red"};

  :hover {
    background: red;
  }
```

Alternatively, if you have multiple CSS rules, then you can interpolate outside of a CSS property:

```css
  ${({ isHovered }) => isHovered && "background: red;color: white;"};

  :hover {
    background: red;
  }
```

Now you just would pass your component an `isHovered` prop.

```
<StyledComponent isHovered={isHovered} />
```

---

Although, technically you can do this (notice that **falsey values** equate to **true**, which may be a **bug** or an **unhandled edge case**) ...

```css
${({ isHovered }) => !isHovered && ".hovered"}, &:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

...it is **NOT** recommended because of how it's being interpreted:

```css
".hovered", &:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

Arguably, this isn't what you'd want because `.hovered` isn't being used **at all** within the DOM, which may be confusing to other developers. Instead, it reuses the compiled hashed class name to add the CSS property within another rule (focus on the `Styles` tab to see the difference):
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqaBF.png)

While the recommended approach sets the CSS property to the hashed class within the same rule block:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hODol.png)

---

**Working demo** (this demo includes both example codes above, where `Title` uses the recommended approach and `SubTitle` doesn't):

[image: Edit Styled Components - Parent Hover]

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const getHoverStyle = (props) => {
   if(props?.isHovered) {
       return ( 
         css` 
            &:hover {
               background: red;
            } 
         `
       )
    }
 }
 export const SomeName = styled.div`
    ${getHoverStyle}
 `;
```

Comment: Check isHovered in props like props?.isHovered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class` selector to apply style and in your styled component you can use `attr` call to set `className` attribute based on property value like:

```
const MyComp = styled.div.attrs((props) => ({
  className: props.isHovered ? "hovered" : ""
}))`
  color: ${(props) => props.color};
  &.hovered,
  &:hover {
    color: blue;
  }
`;
```

Take a look at [this react sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-vvtq3).

Comment: @BryceSnyder is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I have created an interactive playground. You can visit the below link. It might help you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-sky-vp8d9?file=/src/App.js

Below is the code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const HoverExample = styled.div`
  background: pink;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80px;

  ${(props) =>
    props.isHovered &&
    css`
      &:hover {
        background: green;
      }
    `}
`;

export default function App() {
  const [isHovered, setisHovered] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setisHovered(!isHovered)}>
        {!isHovered ? "Enable" : "disabled"} Hover
      </button>
      <p>Hover is {isHovered ? "enabled" : "disabled"}</p>
      <HoverExample isHovered={isHovered}></HoverExample>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks.